# Age Gate splash on Tumblr

Tags: cookies, tumblr

I am attempting to add this script http://codepen.io/blixxurd/pen/PZQVMy to a tumblr page and have had no luck in making the buttons work.

Looks great, shows up on page load but clicking the buttons seems to do nothing. Any advice would be great.

**Here is the javascript:**

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  var cookieHandlers = {

    createCookie : function(name,value,days) {
      if (days) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
      }
      else var expires = "";
      document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    },

    readCookie : function(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    },

    eraseCookie : function(name) {
        cookieHandlers.createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }
  };

  var ageGate = {
    element  : document.getElementById("ageGate"),
    sorryWarning  : document.getElementById("ageSorryWarning"),
    contentWrap : document.getElementById("ageContentWrap"),
    cookieName  : "forever21_or_older",
    select   : function(e) {
      if(e=="yes") {
        cookieHandlers.createCookie(ageGate.cookieName, "true", 30);
        ageGate.actions.hide();
      } else {
        ageGate.contentWrap.style.display = "none";
        ageGate.sorryWarning.style.display = "block";
      }
    },
    actions : {
      show  : function() {
        ageGate.element.style.display = "block";
      }, 
      hide  : function() {
        ageGate.element.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  };

  //Pop Age Gate on Page Load
  if(cookieHandlers.readCookie(ageGate.cookieName)==null) {
    ageGate.actions.show();
  }

});
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="ageGate">
  <div  class="age-content-wrapper" id="ageSorryWarning">
    <strong>Sorry, you must be 21 years of age or older to view this site.</strong><br><br>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://google.com/">Leave Website</a>
  </div>
  <div class="age-content-wrapper" id="ageContentWrap">
    <strong class="age-heading">Are you at least 21 years old?</strong>
    <div class="age-controls">
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="ageGate.select('yes')" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Yes</a>
      <a href="javascript:;" onclick="ageGate.select('no')" class="btn btn-large btn-danger">No</a>
    </div>
    <span class="age-subhead">This website facilitates the sale of alcoholic beverages. We use cookies to assist in verifying age.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix:

```
  var cookieHandlers = {

    createCookie : function(name,value,days) {
      if (days) {
          var date = new Date();
          date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
          var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
      }
      else var expires = "";
      document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    },

    readCookie : function(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    },

    eraseCookie : function(name) {
        cookieHandlers.createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }
  };

  var ageGate = {
    element  : null,
    sorryWarning  : null,
    contentWrap : null,
    cookieName  : "forever21_or_older",
    select   : function(e) {
      if(e=="yes") {
        cookieHandlers.createCookie(ageGate.cookieName, "true", 30);
        ageGate.actions.hide();
      } else {
        ageGate.contentWrap.style.display = "none";
        ageGate.sorryWarning.style.display = "block";
      }
    },
    actions : {
      show  : function() {
        ageGate.element.style.display = "block";
      }, 
      hide  : function() {
        ageGate.element.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  };


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  ageGate.element = document.getElementById("ageGate");
  ageGate.sorryWarning  = document.getElementById("ageSorryWarning");
  ageGate.contentWrap = document.getElementById("ageContentWrap");

    //Pop Age Gate on Page Load
  if(cookieHandlers.readCookie(ageGate.cookieName)==null) {
    ageGate.actions.show();
  }

});
```